# How do I turn off Entity Framework tracking

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have declared my `DbContext` as:

```
public abstract class LouisHoweDbContext : DbContext
{
    // lots of code
}

public class NoTrackingDbContext : LouisHoweDbContext
{
    public NoTrackingDbContext(DbContextOptions<NoTrackingDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    }
}
```

And in `Program.cs` I have:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<NoTrackingDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("LouisHoweDb"),
        x =>
        {
            x.UseNetTopologySuite();
            x.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
        })
);
```

I then use it as:

```
await using (var context = await NoTrackingDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
{
    // ....
}
```

But in that code, using the debugger,

```
dbContext._options.Extensions<CoreOptionsExtension>.QueryTrackingBehavior == TrackAll.
```

Does this mean it is tracking? And if so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the debugger value you are checking, but `dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior` should reveal the current tracking state.  You can also check `dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count` which would reveal if any entities have any pending changes. If you want to verify if any entities in a set happen to be cached, you can look at the `.Local`. For instance `if (dbContext.MyEntities.Local.Any()) throw new InvalidOperation("Local tracking is enabled.");`

Checked this with and without `UseQueryTrackingBehavior` and it looked to be consistent. (EF Core 7)

Comment: That worked great and it's as I expect. thanks